# Uncheck checkbox if another is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So i have the following 2 checkboxes on my page on small script attached to it which is designed to hide the billing section.

```
<script>

function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("billing_info");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>
```

I'm using the below script to try and uncheck the checkboxes

```
    <script>
          $(document).ready( function a()
{
   if (  $('#sameAsBilling').is(':checked'))
    {
       $('#check2').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
</script>




        <div class="header">
           <h3 class="checkout-headers">STEP 3 - Billing Information </h3>
          <!--START: sameAsBilling1-->
<!--value="ON"-->
          <div class="sameAsBilling1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sameAsBilling" id="sameAsBilling" onclick="showHideShipping();check_address('');"/>
            <label for="sameAsBilling">Same as Delivery Address</label>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
            <div class="differentBilling">
                <input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check2" onclick="myFunction2()"; return false;>Different Billing Address?</div>
          <!--END: sameAsBilling1-->
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

My problem is someone as buried the following code in a javascript file which is what transfers the delivery details onto the billing details if the specific checkbox is ticked.

```
  function showHideShipping() {

     if (document.billing.sameAsBilling.checked) {
      add_overlay("billing_info", 0);

       if (get_Element('billing_firstname').value != get_Element('shipping_firstname').value) {
        get_Element('billing_firstname').value = get_Element('shipping_firstname').value;
        get_Element('billing_lastname').value = get_Element('shipping_lastname').value;
        get_Element('billing_company').value = get_Element('shipping_company').value;
        get_Element('billing_phone').value = get_Element('shipping_phone').value;
        get_Element('billing_address').value = get_Element('shipping_address').value;
        get_Element('billing_address2').value = get_Element('shipping_address2').value;
        get_Element('billing_city').value = get_Element('shipping_city').value;
        get_Element('billing_zip').value = get_Element('shipping_zip').value;
        get_Element('billing_country').value = get_Element('shipping_country').value;
        populateState('billing_state', 'billing_country');
        get_Element('billing_state').value = get_Element('shipping_state').value;
      }
    } else {
      remove_overlay("billing_info");

    get_Element('billing_firstname').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_lastname').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_company').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_phone').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_address').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_address2').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_city').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_zip').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_country').value = get_Element('shipping_country').value;
      populateState('billing_state', 'billing_country');
      get_Element('billing_state').value = get_Element('shipping_state').value;


    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain "My problem is someone as buried the following code in a javascript file which is what transfers the delivery details onto the billing details if the specific checkbox is ticked." a bit more? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: can't you make the check to if (x is checked && y is checked) ?

Comment: Is there a missing `else` on the line before `remove_overlay('billing_info')`?

Comment: Basically, i've just started at a company i've been there 2 days as a new intern. I'm trying to fix up their checkout page. On their backend is their js files which has a checkout validate js file which as the code i posted on it (as well as other stuff).

Comment: I tried adding an else into the place you suggested but it just made the page not function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `else`. So the code that hides the billing info and copies the shipping info to it is executed all the time, regardless of the state of the checkbox.

```
   if (document.billing.sameAsBilling.checked) {
      add_overlay("billing_info", 0);

      get_Element('billing_firstname').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_lastname').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_company').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_phone').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_address').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_address2').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_city').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_zip').value = '';
      get_Element('billing_country').value = get_Element('shipping_country').value;
      populateState('billing_state', 'billing_country');
      get_Element('billing_state').value = get_Element('shipping_state').value;
    } else {
      remove_overlay("billing_info");
      if (get_Element('billing_firstname').value != get_Element('shipping_firstname').value) {
        get_Element('billing_firstname').value = get_Element('shipping_firstname').value;
        get_Element('billing_lastname').value = get_Element('shipping_lastname').value;
        get_Element('billing_company').value = get_Element('shipping_company').value;
        get_Element('billing_phone').value = get_Element('shipping_phone').value;
        get_Element('billing_address').value = get_Element('shipping_address').value;
        get_Element('billing_address2').value = get_Element('shipping_address2').value;
        get_Element('billing_city').value = get_Element('shipping_city').value;
        get_Element('billing_zip').value = get_Element('shipping_zip').value;
        get_Element('billing_country').value = get_Element('shipping_country').value;
        populateState('billing_state', 'billing_country');
        get_Element('billing_state').value = get_Element('shipping_state').value;
      }
    }
```

Comment: So that seems to function well the only issue is it only works when the 'same as delivery' checkbox gets unselected

Comment: Swapped the elements around (updated OP) as i don't know why they were the way round they were. In my head, you would get everything when the same as delivery button is checked.

Comment: Why do you need two checkboxes? Anyway, the code you added only unchecks the "different billing address" when the page is first loaded, not when the user clicks on something.

Comment: how could i change this?

Comment: Get rid of the second checkbox, it's not needed.

Comment: You could also use radio buttons if you want to alternate them. But a single checkbox is the usual way this is done.

Comment: And to have the billing info showing until they click same as, which would hide it. Would that seem like a decent UX?

Comment: ux.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask questions like that.